# if one value in the array = 'some string'

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array (some values are blank others contain strings)

```
$myarray = array('Anything','Anything','','Something Special','','','Anything',);
```

How can search the array to see if any of the values (it might be more than 1) contain a specfic string eg. 'Something Special'

Comment: `if(array_count_values($myarray)["something Special"] > 1){/*Do stuff*/}`

Comment: Hi, many thanks! Does this look if theres more than 1 value which contains the string? It can be 1 or more.

So it would be:
    if(array_count_values($myarray)["something Special"] >= 1){/*Do stuff*/} 
Right?

Comment: How come this question got -4?

Comment: @marke_sparke I guess because the question is quite simple to google up. There is an article about asking questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Because you can find plenty of recourse on google on how to achieve this. Seems like no efforts were put before u asked here.

Comment: Ok many thanks everyone ..has help me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_search() function of php
check this link [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php
   $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

   $key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
   $key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

or [in_array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

```
<?php
    $people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

    if (in_array("Glenn", $people))
      {
          echo "Match found";
      }
    else
      {
          echo "Match not found";
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through whole array and then save matches into result array.

```
$myarray = array('Anything','Anything','','Something Special','','','Anything',);
$result = [];
foreach($myarray as $key => $value)
{
  if($value == 'Anything')
  {
    $result[] = 'Found in key='.$key;
  }
}

var_dump($result);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Found in key=0"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Found in key=1"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Found in key=6"
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
if (in_array('Something Special', $myarray)) {
    echo 'Found it!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is probably what you need